# remove space or change color between the views in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

As shown in the picture below there is a gap between buttons and text views. i need to remove this space or i need to change its color to primary color. here is my code and snap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFwQl.jpg)

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/splash"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

                android:id="@+id/logo1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mobileRelView"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:onClick="goToMobileForm"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25">

                    <ImageView
                        android:padding="7dp"
                        android:id="@+id/mobile_Image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:elevation="1dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/smartphone"/>


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/mobile_button"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.3"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:text="Mobile"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#424242" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#424242" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:onClick="goToDesktopForm"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/desktop_Image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/compuericon"/>

                    <Button
                        android:text="Desktop"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/desktop_button"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_weight="1.3" />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#424242" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#424242" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:onClick="goToLaptopForm"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/laptop_Image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/laptop" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="Laptop"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/laptop_button"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_weight="1.3"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="#424242" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/logobutton1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:onClick="gotToOthersForm"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/homeappliances_Image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:padding="7dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/washingmachine"/>

                    <Button
                        android:text="Home Appliance"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/homeappliances_button"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                        android:layout_weight="1.3"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#424242" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:onClick="goToDesktopForm"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:id="@+id/cleaning_Image"
                        android:padding="7dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/caricon" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="Automobile"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/cleaning_button"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                        android:layout_weight="1.3"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#424242" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:onClick="gotToOthersForm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:id="@+id/othrs_Image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:padding="7dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:src="@drawable/othersicon" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="Others"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/others_button"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                        android:layout_weight="1.3"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="150sp">

                <!--<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#6A1B9A"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:background="#ffb300"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Why eFix ?" />
                    -->

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/abca" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to use of `Button`. Use `TextView` instead of `Button`.

**#.** I have modified your XML and removed some redundant attributes and updated `ImageView` and `TextView` with proper `weight` and `height`.

**#.** I have added attribute                     `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` to `LinearLayout` to show `ripple` effect when click on it.

**Here is the working code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/splash"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/logo1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mobileRelView"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:onClick="goToMobileForm"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <ImageView
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_Image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:elevation="1dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                    android:text="Mobile" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#424242" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#424242" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:onClick="goToDesktopForm"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <ImageView
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:id="@+id/desktop_Image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desktop_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                    android:text="Desktop" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#424242" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#424242" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:onClick="goToLaptopForm"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <ImageView
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:id="@+id/laptop_Image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/laptop_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                    android:text="Laptop" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#424242" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/logobutton1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:onClick="gotToOthersForm"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/homeappliances_Image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/homeappliances_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                    android:text="Home Appliance" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#424242" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:onClick="goToDesktopForm"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cleaning_Image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:padding="7dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cleaning_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                    android:text="Automobile" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#424242" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:onClick="gotToOthersForm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/othrs_Image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:padding="7dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/others_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mainbuttontext"
                    android:text="Others"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="150sp">

            <!--<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#6A1B9A"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="#ffb300"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Why eFix ?" />
                -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]